# Running PS1 file from batch file, same folder on thumb drive

Tags: powershell, batch-file, drive

Admittedly I'm no scripter.  I piece together what already works but trying to learn.

I have a script that does a lot of the manual labor for setting up a scan user for myself and our techs.  Here is a small portion of it written as a batch file.  At the end before the pause I want to call a PowerShell to show what the Network type is, not to change it.  At least not at this time. I did remove alot of the extra from the file to save space.  Both the batch file and the PS1 file will be in the same folder on a thumb drive.

The nettype.ps1 file just has:

```
get-netconnectionprofile
pause
```

The pause of course is so the tech can see the network type.

Hope someone has a simple solution.  I did look here and other websites. I may not be using the right terminology in my search or understanding what I need done.

```
net user Scans Scanner1 /add
net localgroup administrators Scans /add
wmic UserAccount where Name='Scans' set PasswordExpires=False
md C:\Scans
@echo off

NET SHARE Scans=C:\Scans /Grant:Scans,Full
ICACLS "C:\Scans" /Grant Scans:(OI)(CI)(F) /t /c
ICACLS "C:\Scans" /Grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)(F) /t /c
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Network Discovery" new enable=Yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=Yes
PowerShell.exe -File "nettype.ps1"
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is all you have inside your [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script, don't run it as a script, delete it and just run the command directly in your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "Get-NetConnectionProfile"
```

Which could be probably be shortened to:

```
PowerShell Get-NetConnectionProfile
```

Comment: I like that better.  Don't need to worry about an external file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, knew it would be simple.

Just had to use the following in the batch file:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dp0nettype.ps1""
```

Comment: It's funny how many times the answer comes to us after making the question, great work.

Comment: Most definitely.  Was looking for the answer for 3 days.  After posting I found out how to do it with a hard path.  Then found they way it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the powershell call to the following to find the ps1 file in the same directory:

```
powershell.exe -File "%~dp0nettype.ps1"
```

`%~dp0` is a combination of `%0` variable and `~d` and `~p` modifiers.

- `%0` is the full path to the current batch file.
- `~d` when combined with `%0` (e.g. `%~d0`)  will get you drive letter portion (e.g. C:) from `%0`.
- `~p` when combined with `%0` (e.g. `%~p0`) will get you the path portion of `%0` without the filename.
- Combining them together, `%~dp0`, will get you the full path of the folder where current batch file is located.

You can find a complete list of these modifiers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490909(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

One thing to note, is that `%~dp0` modifier only works in batch files, not when you try to run on commandline directly.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.